# Kill Subprocess in Python after timeout

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I searchedon internet and learned other method of implementing it
the problem now i have found out. my execution time always becomes more than that 
of time out if i write  stdout=subprocess.PIPE in subprocess.Popen. If i am removing it then it is taking normal execution time

```
import subprocess, datetime, os, time, signal
//setting time for timeout
timeout=3
start = datetime.datetime.now()
process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "/home/bourne/untitled.py"],shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while process.poll() is None:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        if (now - start).seconds > timeout:
            os.kill(process.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
            os.waitpid(-1, os.WNOHANG)
            print "error"       
            print (now - start).seconds
            break
        print (now - start).seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have successfully solved the problem. the solution is 

import subprocess, signal, os, threading, errno
from contextlib import contextmanager

class TimeoutThread(object):
    def __init__(self, seconds):
        self.seconds = seconds
        self.cond = threading.Condition()
        self.cancelled = False
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self._wait)

    def run(self):
        """Begin the timeout."""
        self.thread.start()

    def _wait(self):
        with self.cond:
            self.cond.wait(self.seconds)

            if not self.cancelled:
                self.timed_out()

    def cancel(self):
        """Cancel the timeout, if it hasn't yet occured."""
        with self.cond:
            self.cancelled = True
            self.cond.notify()
        self.thread.join()

    def timed_out(self):
        """The timeout has expired."""
        raise NotImplementedError

class KillProcessThread(TimeoutThread):
    def __init__(self, seconds, pid):
        super(KillProcessThread, self).__init__(seconds)
        self.pid = pid

    def timed_out(self):
        try:
            os.kill(self.pid, signal.SIGKILL) // this is for linux you need to change it for windows
        except OSError,e:
            # If the process is already gone, ignore the error.
            if e.errno not in (errno.EPERM, errno. ESRCH):
                raise e

@contextmanager
def processTimeout(seconds, pid):
    timeout = KillProcessThread(seconds, pid)
    timeout.run()
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        timeout.cancel()


def example(cmd):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    //setting the timeout to be 1 sec
    with processTimeout(1, proc.pid):
        stdout,stderr=proc.communicate()       

    resultcode = proc.wait()
    if resultcode &lt; 0:
        #print "error: %i" % resultcode
        return resultcode,0
    else:
        return stdout,stderr





//This is used to create new subprocess and it will return output as well as error
output,err=example(["python",filepath,"5"])
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't spawn a new thread just for having it time out in 5 seconds and then use it's `isAlive` status as break condition for a busy wait. You don't need an extra thread for that, you can messure the time in the first thread.

Instead of polling the thread as often as you can, you should use a delay (`time.sleep`) to allow the processor to do some real work.

And you should know that if your process is generating a lot of output, it will block if you don't read it while the process is executing and let it fill up the pipe's buffer.

Comment: I searched internet and found other way of implementing it.  thanks for your reply.Now i am having problem with stdout=subprocess.PIPE. If i write it then it is taking more execution time else normal execution time.

Comment: @KevalVora - you still seem to read the pipe only after the process has finnished. If the pipe's buffer is full, then the subprocess will hang until you read from it or it is killed. And using `time.time` instead of `datetime` would be faster.

Comment: I need to run the program submitted by user and check whether it has executed successfully or not if there is infinite loop i need to kill that process and I need to show the output to the user. can you suggest any solution for this?

Comment: yes, just read the output (stdout/stdin) while the process is running. __that__ is something you could do in a second thread.

Answer (score 0):

Thread can be handled in python VM, but process not.
so u have to use OS api to kill ur process/subprocess, such as (in linux):

```
os.system("kill -9 %s"%(proc.pid))
```

and, using thread for timing is a bad idea. how about:

```
start_t = time.time()
TIME_END, TIME_SLEEP = 5, 1
while time.time() - start_t < TIME_END:
    if proc.poll():
        break
    time.sleep(TIME_SLEEP)
```

Comment: I searched internet and found other way of implementing it. thanks for your reply.Now i have updated my question and i am having problem with stdout=subprocess.pipe.